# need help in SQL Server Query

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table say Student . This has 2 columns studentid and classid

Anotehr table Class which has ClassID and ClassDescription

Assume , Class has values

```
ClassID ClassDescription
1 A
2 B
3 C
4 D
5 E
```

I want to create a query to find out students who have attended A and B .  This should be a dynamic query so that next time I require a qry to find out students who have attended A, B and C or  B, C and D I should be able to use it.

Comment: Please make it clear. what do you mean of: "next time I require a qry to find out students who have attended A, B and C or B, C and D"

Answer (score 0):

Create a new table `filterClass` to be your dinamic source like

```
FilterID
'A'
'B'
'C'
```

Then your query is

```
SELECT S.StudentID 
FROM Student S
JOIN Class C
  ON S.class_id = C.class_id 
JOIN filterClass F
  ON C.ClassDescription = F.FilterID
GROUP BY S.StudentID 
HAVING COUNT(C.ClassDescription) = (SELECT COUNT(FilterID) FROM filterClass)
```

In this case `SELECT COUNT(FilterID) FROM filterClass` will be 3 `(A,B,C)`